# Повторный рендеринг в react из-за ajax запроса

Tags: reactjs

Здравствуйте, изучаю react.js для ajax использую пакет axios.
Суть в том что в `componentDidMount()` я делаю запрос к внешнему api и от туда получаю объект с данными, сейчас в приложение происходит такое:
1) Рендерится пустой объект, а потом заполняется данными с api и повторно рендерится. На скриншоте показано красным первый рендеринг пустого массива, и второй рендеринг уже массива с данными. Я это ссылаю на то что в `DidMount` изменяя state повторно запускается рендеринг компонента, можно это как то изменить? или придется на сервере делать api запрос и уже потом отдавать его реакту?

P.S
И просьба к знатокам если что то в коде я сделал не правильно указать на это:) Только учусь понимать работу реакта:)

[image: 2 рендеринга в консоле]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
const currencyPair = [
    {name: "Все валюты", zip: "All",},
    {name: "Биткоин", zip: "BTC_USD"},
    {name: "Ефериум", zip: "ETH_USD"},
    {name: "Лайткоин", zip: "LTC_USD"}
];
const URL = "https://api.exmo.me/v1/ticker/";
class ExchangeRate extends Component {
    render() {
       let currency = this.props.currency;
       let content;
        console.log(this.props.rate);
        if (currency === "All") {
            content =<span>Вывод курса всех валют <br/> {'BTC_USD' in this.props.rate ? currencyPair.map((place, index) => (

            place.zip !== "All" ? <div key={index}>{place.zip} = {this.props.rate[place.zip].last_trade}</div>: ''

            )) : 'Ошибка ведутся технические работы'}
        </span>
        } else {
            content = <span>Вывод курса по валютной паре {currency}
            - {'BTC_USD' in this.props.rate ? this.props.rate[currency].last_trade : 'Ошибка ведутся технические работы'} </span>
    }
    return (
        <h1>{content}</h1>
    );

    }
}
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        activePlace: 1,
        rate: {}
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
        axios.post(URL)
            .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({
                    rate: response.data
                })
            }.bind(this))
}
render() {
    const activePlace = this.state.activePlace;
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="App-header">
                <span className="App-title">Курс крипто валюты</span>
            </div>
            <div className="App-intro">
                <span>Выберите валютную пару</span>
            </div>
            {currencyPair.map((place, index) => (
                <button
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({activePlace: index});
                    }}
                >
                    {place.name}
                </button>
            ))}
            <ExchangeRate key={activePlace} currency={currencyPair[activePlace].zip} rate={this.state.rate}/>
        </div>

    );
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Рендерится пустой объект, а потом заполняется данными с api и повторно
>   рендерится. На скриншоте показано красным первый рендеринг пустого
>   массива, и второй рендеринг уже массива с данными. Я это ссылаю на то
>   что в DidMount изменяя state повторно запускается рендеринг
>   компонента

У вас всё работает как надо. Рендеринг происходит каждый раз, когда изменяется внутреннее состояние компонента (то есть *props* (то, что задаётся снаружи) или *state* (то, что задаётся самим компонентом)).
Как только объект *rate* изменится, ваш компонент перерисуется (причём не только **ExchangeRate**, но и **App**, так как в нём вы меняете *state*).

> можно это как то изменить? или придется на сервере делать
>   api запрос и уже потом отдавать его реакту?

А зачем? Почему нельзя обновлять данные на клиенте в рантайме? Ведь ajax вроде как затем и придумали.

По поводу кода - я бы вынес различные компоненты в разные файлы и, если ограничиваться только реактом, функции, связанные с запросом данных - в отдельную службу. Если используете *redux*, то эти вызовы лучше вынести в action-ы.

Comment: redux не использую, спасибо за советы:)
По поводу рендеринга, то он происходит 2 раза подряд то есть загружается приложение и тут же происходит 2 - ой рендеринг, из-за этого если я не предотвращаю ошибки связаные с  пустым объектом то приложение начинает крашится.
В этом и была суть, хотелось как то избавится от этого и что бы ajax запрос происходил при первом  рендеринге :) Я могу запустить сервер что бы проблему потрогать в реальности)

Answer (score 1):

Для чего делать запрос после того как компонент отрендерился (componentDidMount)? Есть же метод componentWillMount.

Как совет, разделите render на несколько частей:

```
render() {
    <div>
        {this.staticPart()}
        {this.dymamicPart()}
    <div>
}
```

Где staticPart - функция возвращающая статичную часть страницы, а dymamicPart - та, которая требует каких то данных с сервера. staticPart у вас неизменна и поэтому может отрендерится сразу, а dymamicPart напишите подобным образом:

```
function dymamicPart() {
    // проверка пустой ли объект (можно воспользоваться библиотекой lodash: _.isEmpty(...)
    const isEmpty = Object.keys(this.state.rate).length === 0 && this.state.rate.constructor === Object
    if (isEmpty) {
         return null
    }
    return ...
}
```

Если внутри функции не будет this, то сделайте привязку в constructor() или используйте стрелочные функции

```
dymamicPart = () => {...}
```

Comment: Метод componentWillMount лучше не использовать для AJAX-запросов. В будущем от него планируют отказаться. Коротко здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043832/why-componentwillmount-should-not-be-used и более подробно тут https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html
По этим соображениям использование **componentDidMount** является предпочтительным.

Comment: @Dan согласен, но ведь только в 17 версии

Comment: Там смысл не только в том, что в будущем его выпилят, но и в том, что componentWillMount часто неправильно используется. И по первой ссылке объясняется, почему лучше использовать именно **componentDidMount**.

Comment: Понимаю, но то для того чтобы избежать проблем с повторным рендерингом я написал условие: if (isEmpty) { return null }.